# How to create a bordered box with specific dimensions for a character in text?

Tags: css

If I have a character (say “+”) inside text and I would like to place it in a bordered box, I can just wrap it in a `span` and set `border: solid 1px` of course. But what if I wish to have specific dimensions for the box, like 0.5em by 0.5em? By default, `span` is inline, so `width` and `height` are ignored.

I thought setting `display: inline-box` would help, but this seems to cause the borders to be drawn in odd ways, so that the character is not in the box at all, and differently in different browsers; see http://jsfiddle.net/csMLu/

Is there something I need to set on the element, or is there a better basic approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `line height` and `text-align` seems to make it work, however the `0.5em` container is to small for the text.

```css
.box05 {
    height: .5em;
    width: .5em;
    line-height: .5em;
    font-size: .9em  /* smaller then the others */
}

.box06 {
    height: .6em;
    width: .6em;
    line-height: .6em;
}

.box07 {
    height: .7em;
    width: .7em;
    line-height: .7em;
}

.box08 {
    height: .8em;
    width: .8em;
    line-height: .8em;
}

.box09 {
    height: .9em;
    width: .9em;
    line-height: .9em;
}


p { margin: 1em; }
span { border: solid #444 1px; text-align: center; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<p>Use the <span class="box05">+</span> button!

<p>Use the <span class="box06">+</span> button!
    
<p>Use the <span class="box07">+</span> button!
    
<p>Use the <span class="box08">+</span> button!
    
<p>Use the <span class="box09">+</span> button!
```

Comment: The `line-height` setting did it. However I modified the CSS a bit, in order to place the character in the middle of the box and simultaneously appearing in line with other characters (just fine-tuning for purposes that weren’t expressed). It is also essential to keep `display: inline-block` to make the dimensioning work in standards mode. http://jsfiddle.net/csMLu/19/

Answer (score 0):

you were setting you class wrong

it works fine once you set the style to inline-block

http://jsfiddle.net/csMLu/15/

Comment: As far as I can see, you have just removed the `width` and `height` settings, and the question was about setting specific dimensions. There was no problem in drawing the borders as such (even without `display: inline-block`) but in their rendering when specific dimensions are set.